# Rails 4 / Heroku Internal Server Error in 390ms + Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an web app that requires users to update images. I have installed this using the Paperclip gem. This works on localhost. However on Heroku it does upload the image but when they click on back button to view the listings.index file I get Internal Server Error.

```
20:       <tr>
2014-07-21T16:18:42.727180+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 390ms
2014-07-21T16:18:42.726840+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (383.4ms)
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729352+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:   <tbody>
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729353+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
2014-07-21T16:18:42.726897+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (383.4ms)
2014-07-21T16:18:42.727145+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 390ms
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729361+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:         <td><%= listing.price %></td>
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729366+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729418+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:         <td><%= image_tag listing.image.url(:small) %></td>
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729422+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:         <td><%= listing.price %></td>
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729410+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/small/1_mangos.jpg' not found):
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729365+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb___3465202124191925527_69930398073120'
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729360+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:         <td><%= listing.description %></td>
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729440+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/l
istings/index.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb___3465202124191925527_69930398073120'
2014-07-21T16:18:42.729357+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:         <td><%= image_tag listing.image.url(:small) %></td>
```

listings.index.html.erb

```
<h3>Product Listings </h3>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= image_tag listing.image.url(:small) %></td>
        <td><%= listing.name %></td>
        <td><%= listing.description %></td>
        <td><%= listing.price %></td>
        <td><%= listing.quantity %></td>
        <td><%= listing.company %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', listing, class: "btn btn-link" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(listing), class: "btn btn-link" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', listing, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-link" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Product Listing', new_listing_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
   <p><%= @listing.price %></p>
  <p><%= @listing.description %></p>
  <p><%= @listing.quantity %></p>
  <p><%= @listing.company %></p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', listings_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
ruby "2.0.0"
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip' 
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem "paperclip-dropbox", ">= 1.1.7"
gem "figaro"

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end


at=info method=GET path="/" host=sincurudemo.herokuapp.com request_id=9c2482eb-dd09-42a0-80fc-905a729209dd fwd="185.30.24.132" dyno=web.1 connect=11 service=468 status=500 bytes=1090
2014-07-21T17:19:33.329057+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (444.7ms)
2014-07-21T17:19:33.329212+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 446ms
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331035+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331056+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/small/1_mangos.jpg' not found):
2014-07-21T17:19:33.329050+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (444.7ms)
2014-07-21T17:19:33.329199+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 446ms
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331061+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:       <tr>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331060+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331063+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:         <td><%= listing.name %></td>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331066+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:         <td><%= listing.price %></td>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331067+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_listings_index_html_erb__108501327453821717_70092909422920'
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331070+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331077+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331079+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Path '/small/1_mangos.jpg' not found):
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331058+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:   <tbody>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331080+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:   <tbody>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331081+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:     <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331072+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331082+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:       <tr>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331062+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:         <td><%= image_tag listing.image.url(:small) %></td>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331065+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:         <td><%= listing.description %></td>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331069+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb__108501327453821717_70092909422920'
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331083+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:         <td><%= image_tag listing.image.url(:small) %></td>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331085+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:         <td><%= listing.description %></td>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331087+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:         <td><%= listing.price %></td>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331089+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb__108501327453821717_70092909422920'
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331084+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:         <td><%= listing.name %></td>
2014-07-21T17:19:33.331088+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/listings/index.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_listings_index_html_erb__108501327453821717_70092909422920'
```

listing.rb file

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  if Rails.env.development?
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "50x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)

  else
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg",
        :storage => :dropbox,
        :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
        :path => ":style/:id_:filename"
  end
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)
  validates_attachment_presence :image
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior for serving assets in Rails 4 apps on Heroku has changed since Rails 3.2.

First, enable static asset serving in `production.rb`: `config.serve_static_assets = true`.

Then, add the [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem to your `Gemfile`: `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

Also (per the discussion with OP), you don't have the `:small` key defined in your `has_attached_file` for `Listing.rb` on non-development environments:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "50x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)

else
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg",
    :storage => :dropbox,
    :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
    :path => ":style/:id_:filename"
end
```

So once you add `:small => "50x"` within the `else` block it should work.

Comment: Changed assets to true and already had the rails_12factor gem , recompiled - now the app won't even start

Comment: Are you grouping the `rails_12factor` gem in `production` only in your Gemfile? Also, what error(s) are you getting since restarting the server? Is it crashing locally or on Heroku?

Comment: works locally but not on heroku - have updated the latest logs

Comment: Try commenting out the `image_tag` helpers in your view. Also, what do the Heroku logs display in regards to the errors causing the crash?

Comment: It seems like your issue is with the image urls being rendered in the view. Are you precompiling assets locally before each Heroku deployment or do you have `config.assets.compile = true` in your `production.rb` file?

Comment: if i comment out the image_tag it gives me the urls , i have posted the heroku logs display in regards of the errors

Comment: production.rb config.assets.compile = true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57696/discussion-between-mmichael-and-neil).